# Python requests and my browser aren't giving me the same result

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha

I was trying to extract data from a website with the python requests library

When I launched the request from my browser, I got the data
When I launched the request from requests library, I got a captcha

So I guess that website doesn't want me to extract its data and it's fine, but it made me curious.

How can I get different results from a same request ? Headers were the same, URLs were the same too

Comment: Browser can send cookies. Also, another agent, maybe something else. Have you tried the same from incognito mode?

Comment: Some JS processing on the page? `requests` can't deal with JS code

Comment: I removed the browser cookies before. Same User-agent. Still no captcha from incognito mode

Comment: @IvanVinogradov When I took the cookies my browser was genereting and put them into the headers of the request with python requets library, it worked. Doesn't it mean that JS processing isn't the issue ?

Comment: You can temporarily disable JS in your browser and test whether result will be the same

Comment: I disabled JS. I still get good results, but no captcha in my browser.